# Javascript fails to execute properly for some images

Tags: javascript

I'm building my personal e-commerce website with vertical rhythm in mind. It's just a challenge for myself. But images are so problematic for me. I need to set their height using javascript (script below?), for some images it's executed properly but not some others. The not executed properly images will have 0 height.

I've tried using window.onload but still don't work. I also looking for proper vanilla JS plugin but none of them available to use.

```
function adjustImg(element) {
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName(element),
      lineHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('line-height')),
      newLineHeight = lineHeight / 2;

  for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var aspectRatio = images[i].offsetWidth / images[i].offsetHeight,
        originalHeight = images[i].offsetWidth / aspectRatio,
        div = Math.round(originalHeight / newLineHeight),
        newHeight = newLineHeight * div;
    images[i].style.height = newHeight + 'px';
  }
}
```

I expected all images to have corrected height properly. But like I said some of them don't show up because of the 0 height. My hypothesis is because the image is not completely loaded, but the javascript has been executed. Therefore the javascript could not obtain the offsetWidth and offsetHeight

I've no idea how to fix this issue, any helps are much appreciated. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try [img.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload). This event fires when an image is loaded.